# .swf coming out chunky when embedded

Tags: flash

I have a client who has exported an animation from After Effects to swf.  The file comes out to about 180k and looks super crisp.  However, when I embed it in an html page, it comes out all chunky.  you can see a test [HERE](http://camandbenny.com/flash/).  Any flash experts have any ideas ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
object {
        height: 100%;
        width: auto;
        }
```

I thought I could make this responsive... but that seemed to be the culprit.